Is "Grand Chawhee" a misspelling of "Grand Chalky"?
In "All Dogs Go to Heaven" (1989) an orphan girl and a would-be criminal/businessman named "Charlie" place a bet on a horse in a horse race.
The name of the horse is

"Grand Chawhee".

People occasionally name their horses after the color of the horse's coat...


Blacky the black stallion.

Old Red the red stallion.

Blanca the white mare.




Is "Grand Chawhee" a non-standard spelling and/or non-standard pronunciation of "Grand Chalky"?
